# PHP - merge two arrays similar to array_combine, but with duplicate keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$arrKeys = array('str', 'str', 'otherStr');
$arrVals = array('1.22', '1.99', '5.17');
```

I would like to merge them into something like this

```
$arrResult = array(
    array('str' => 1.22),
    array('str' => 1.99),
    array('otherStr' => 5.17)
);
```

The keys are non-unique, otherwise I'd use `array_combine`. That would give a bit different output, but it would suit me as well.

Can this be done in an elegant way using PHP 5.2.x, without `foreach`/`for` loops, preferably using PHP's built-in functions?

Comment: You can't have non-unique keys in a php array.

Comment: @chelmertz - yes, that is why I'm not using array_combine and the result I would like to obtain is a bit different, as in my example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$arrKeys = array('str', 'str', 'otherStr');
$arrVals = array('1.22', '1.99', '5.17');
function foo($key, $val) {
   return array($key=>$val);
}

$arrResult = array_map('foo', $arrKeys, $arrVals);

print_r($arrResult);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [str] => 1.22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [str] => 1.99
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [otherStr] => 5.17
        )

)
```

BTW, if you upgrade to PHP 5.3 you can do this using an anonymous function, which is a bit more elegant:

```
array_map(function($key, $val) {return array($key=>$val);}, $arrKeys, $arrVals);
```

Comment: I wonder why would someone down-vote this after it was accepted without adding a comment

Answer (score 10):

**There is absolutely nothing "elegant" in using PHP's built-in functions** and nothing to pursue for.

This is not a *Haute Couture* show. This is programming.
As long as you have a solution that is sane, readable and works, you can call it elegant.

Simple foreach will do the job.  You'd do yourself huge favor and save a lot of time if start using working solutions instead of looking for "elegant" ones.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($arrKeys as $i => $key) {
  $result[] = array($key => $arrVals[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Isn't `array_map` simple *and* elegant?

Comment: no. obfuscating your own code has nothing in common with elegance

Comment: I have no problems reading `array_map`, but indeed here I think just a simple loop is a helluvalot clearer for the next guy....

Comment: like the way you do it dude.. :)

Comment: lol. PHP's built in functions are optimized and compiled in C -- i.e **much** faster than the hackey crap you will write with your "sane, readable, elegant" **PHP code**. Use the optimized low level code as much as possible.

Comment: Bro It worked fine, but it was creating nested array so i changed it to $result[$key][] = $arrVals[$i];   this in the foreach loop. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want item 0 in `$arrKeys` and item 0 in `$arrVals` to be added to one array, and that array to be an item in `$arrResult`, and so on, the easiest way would probably be a simple loop:

```
$arrResult = array();
for ($i = 0, $max = count($arrKeys); $i < $max; $i++) {
    $arrResult[] = array($arrKeys[$i], $arrValues[$i]);
}
```