# Merging two arrays then sorting them

Tags: php, sorting, merge, associative-array

Beginner here. I have two arrays, one that contains my values(**$m1**) and the other contains what I want to use as keys(**$pn**) (non unique strings). They have the same length (465) and $pn[0] is the key for $m1[0] value. I merged them to become key-value pairs using a foreach loop like this:

```
$result = array ();
foreach($pn as $key => $value){
    $result[] = array($value => $m1[$key]);
}
```

If I do this and try print_r on $result I do see keys and values assigned. Now I need to get the 93 largest values and their corresponding keys. I tried to use asort but it didn't sort the array by values, it just really messed it up somehow. If anyone had an answer I would really appreciate it. Thank you very much!

Comment: array_combine() is the function you want

Comment: I have non unique strings as keys. array_combine can't do that, it somehow merges values with the same keys. Or something like that happened when I tried to use it. The foreach loop seems to work perfectly, but I can't sort the array it produces.

Comment: If they are non-unique keys, then what do you want to happen?

Comment: once you use array_combine() you should be able to perform an asort on the new array.

Comment: I want to sort the array to get the 93 largest values and their corresponding keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your combined array using [array_combine()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
$result = array_combine(
    $pn,
    $m1
);
```

Then [asort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php), remembering that the argument is passed by reference

```
asort($result);
```

**EDIT**

If you have non-unique keys, then build a combined array using a loop:

```
$result = array();
foreach($pn as $key => $value){
    $result[] = array('key' => $m1[$key], 'value' => $value);
}
```

Then use [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the array:

```
usort(
    $result,
    function ($a, $b) {
        if ($a['value'] == $b['value']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a['value'] > $b['value']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
);
```

And use [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to extract the top 93 entries

Comment: I can't use array combine because of identical keys in my $pn array. For reference here is this question by someone else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078770/php-merge-two-arrays-similar-to-array-combine-but-with-duplicate-keys

Comment: I think I got it working, thank you very very much. May I have a very beginner question? MY original loop created an associative array. Why didn't asort worked on that?

Comment: Your original loop created a nested array; individual associative arrays within an enumerated array.... asort() worked on the top-level (enumerated) array.... my solution isn't dissimilar, but uses usort to force sorting on the value from the individual array elements