# PHP: Combine two arrays keeping duplicate keys?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

How do I combine two arrays where the first array contains duplicate keys? e.g. combine the following:

```
$keys_arr
Array
    (
        [0] => iPhone
        [1] => iPhone
        [2] => iPhone
        [3] => Samsung
    )

$values_arr
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 5
    [3] => Galaxy IV
)
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
$combined_array
Array
    (
        [iPhone] => 5
        [iPhone] => 5
        [iPhone] => 5
        [Samsung] => Galaxy IV
    )
```

Using the following foreach ([PHP - merge two arrays similar to array_combine, but with duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078770/php-merge-two-arrays-similar-to-array-combine-but-with-duplicate-keys)):

```
foreach ($keys_arr as $key => $value) {
    $combined_array[] = array($value => $values_arr[$key]);
}
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [iPhone] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [iPhone] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [iPhone] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Samsung] => Galaxy IV
        )

)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The result you're looking for is not possible because PHP doesn't allow duplicate keys in an array

Comment: Why not try creating `$combined_array
= array(array('iPhone', '5'),
 array('iPhone' ,'5'),
 array('iPhone' ,'5'),
 array('Samsung' ,'Galaxy IV')
);`

Comment: So it looks like you are combining two pieces of information about a single object together.  You might consider combining to an array of objects like `[{'product_line':'iPhone', 'model': '5'}, ... , {'product_line':'Samsung','model': 'Galaxy IV'}]` such that you create a new property name for each of the array values by which you can definitively lookup the information you are trying to store.

Comment: `$combined_array[] = ...` will add a new element (which happens to be an array) to `$combined_array`.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks, I (stupidly) had no idea array keys had to be unique!

Answer (score 0):

php's associative arrays need to have unique keys for values - while you can have values that are all the same (i.e: `5, 5, 5`), the keys MUST be distinct.

One way you can "work around" this is by using a Linked List data structure in the case of duplicates; this would result in;

```
$iPhone = {(5), (5), (5)}

$Samsung = Galaxy IV
```

An easy workaround to accomplish this would be to use a multi-dimensional array; i.e:

`Array[iPhone]` would hold a seperate array, containing `{5, 5, 5}`.

You can read up more on actual linked lists here; http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php